# wp_insert_term doesn't want to enter its data into custom taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, terms

so I'm working on a code to take data from an array and put it in a custom taxonomy using `wp_insert_tem`, but the data won't go in. this is the json i want to fetch, this is from a url

```
{
"genres": [
    {
      "name": "Military"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sci-fi"
    },
    {
      "name": "Shounen"
    }
  ],
}
```

this is the code i made

```
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($array['genres'] as $gen){
    wp_insert_term(
        $gen["name"],
        "genres",
        array(
            "description" => "",
            "slug" => sanitize_title($gen["name"]),
        ),
   );
}
```

**please help me**

Comment: Where is this code running? You need to make sure it’s run after the `genres` taxonomy has been registered. Probably on the `init` hook or later.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I created a custom admin page. I put the code there

Comment: when I try to use $array["genres"][0]["name"] it works, but when I use foreach it doesn't work

Comment: @Soelllll `wp_insert_term()` returns a `WP_Error` object upon failure, so you can try inspecting the return value like so: `$term_arr = wp_insert_term( ... ); if ( is_wp_error( $term_arr ) ) echo $term_arr->get_error_message();`

Comment: @SallyCJ I get an Invalid Taxonomy error. but I think the taxonomy name is correct. `register_taxonomy( 'genres', array( 'manga' ), $args ); `

Comment: @SallyCJ it's the same, I still get the Invalid Taxonomy error

Comment: Try `var_dump( taxonomy_exists( 'manga' ) );` and if it's false, then you need to ensure the taxonomy is registered before your code runs. (Edit: Sorry, ignore my previous comment which I've deleted)

Comment: @SallyCJ it always returns false, even though I've registered the taxonomy above the function I created
this is the picture i took in the code
[link](https://prnt.sc/1rd1bf4)

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant `var_dump( taxonomy_exists( 'genres' ) );` and in the question, you used the correct taxonomy, but in your actual code, did you use `manga`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Of course I use genre, maybe you can see my code here
[gist](https://gist.github.com/Soel30/6ab64a5f7fb3eecbbc47c543d9b0a63e)

Comment: Well then, from a quick look at your code, the taxonomy is not yet registered because your code runs before the `init` hook is fired. Use the relevant hook to run your plugin actions and not running your code at the root of the file like you did. Also, see https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins as a starting guide for doing AJAX in WordPress plugins.

Comment: @SallyCJ ah it's work, thanks